# Can't open folder in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

I started using the Atom Editor a few days ago and I really like it now.
Everything worked perfect, but now if I want to open a folder, it doesn't work and Atom crashes. (There is no error message or something like that.)
I can still open other folders in Atom, just not this one. I tried to open the folder in vscode and it worked. Why could Atom crash when I try to open that one folder?
(In the folder there are folders with .json files and there is a .py and a .txt file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved my problem:
I renamed the folder which Atom couldn't open,
now Atom can open it and everything works.
But if I rename the folder again to its old name, it doesn't work.
Does anyone have an idea why this could happen???

Comment: Could it be that the folder you are trying to open is listed in `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with **Atom**.

I opened the Folder in **File Explorer** and Dragged and Dropped it to **Atom** and it opened it properly.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after  go to

1. file
2. AddProjectFolder
3. from the popup menu select discard changes

I hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was crashing every time it opened the Browse-dialogue, when either trying to save or trying to open.

I was able to use it by opening files from command line.

I tried a few different things, including clicking Add Project Folder. No improvement.

Then I clicked Reopen Project and chose a random one. (I don't really use the project concept, so I haven't opened a project for a long time).

That made the problem disappear.